# For FY 2008-09, in ITR-2, can one mention brokerage value for STCG or STCL, if no proof provided but was paid?

Tags: taxes, india

Due to an income tax query for FY 2008-09 and 2009-10, I need to fill the ITR 2 form. For this there was short term debt gain and loss too. Brokerage was paid @ 0.2%, but without any proof. If I mention brokerage values, will  be any problem due to lack of proof? Because, if I mention the brokerage value then only, I can get rid of tax payment. Without which I may have to pay tax for that FY with interest.

Also, please let me know that while mentioning in the CG section, in full value under consideration, have I to mention the sale value after deducting the losses occurred?

Kindly help me in this respect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are entitled to deduct brokerage costs.

> CG section, in full value under consideration, have I to mention the sale value after deducting the losses occurred?

You have to mentioned the "Sale Value" of Shares.
In the Cost of acquisition, you have to mention how much you paid to buy the shares [including brokerage during buy].
In the Expenditure you have to mention the brokerage for sell.

> Brokerage was paid @ 0.2%, but without any proof.

Not sure I understand this, why don't you have proof.

> If I mention brokerage values, will be any problem due to lack of proof?

Generally proofs are not asked while filing returns. However there can be an enquire on the calculation and one would have to produce proofs. Note the enquire can also ask for evidence on the total sale price or buy price and not just brokerage.

Further read at [Income Tax India](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/tutorials/14-%20stcg.pdf)

Edits:

Every Switch is considered a taxable event. So for example you invested x units at Rs 5000. After 6 months, you switched. Say you got Rs 5500 and bought y units for same funds [say growth to dividend]. Then you again after 6 months you switched to grown, the price was Rs 6000. Then sold it after one month for Rs 6100.

Total sale was Rs 5500 + Rs 6000 + Rs 6100
So your total initial investment is Rs 5000 + Rs 5500 + 6000
Your Total gain taxable will be Rs 1100.

Comment: Thank you for your reply nut I would like to know about  "Sale value". Is it the total amount / money, received after selling the mutual fund? as in my case it was debt mutual fund. Also about brokerage. it was provided in cash. So I don't have any proof. But for sale price and buy price, I have proof as I have mutual fund statements.

Comment: If there is no receipt, there is no brokerage.

Comment: Sir, as I am filing the return, there are many investments which are reinvested, I.e. switched again and again. So the query is adding all the switched amounts too. But the initial investments are less.

Comment: Sir, as I am filing the return, there are many investments which are reinvested, I.e. switched again and again. So the query is adding all the switched amounts too. But the initial investments are less. So I would like to know while filing the return, in  CG section while entering about the initial investment amount, Only initial amounts deducting the switched amounts in which the initial amount is repeated or I have to fill the total values, weather initial or reinvested amounts all together which is much more than the initial actual invested amounts. Kindly please help me in this respect.

Comment: @Ravi See edits. Every switch means you have sold the old units and purchased the new units. If you have done this within a year, its short term capital gains.

Comment: Yes Sir, But I would like to know which amount should be entered in CG section Initial or the total of all these reinvested amounts. Suppose Rs 100000/-invested. Gain is 10,000/- .Then this whole Rs 110000/- is again switched to other scheme, Here gain is 8000/- Then again 118000/- switched and redeemed as Rs 120000/-  In this actual initial investment is Rs 100000/- and gain is Rs 20000/-/- . ( If switches not considered.)  But total initial investments added is Rs 100000/- + Rs 110000/- + Rs 118000/-. That is total Rs 328000/-  So in CG what to enter Initial Investment 100000/-or Rs 328000/-

Comment: @Ravi Rs 32800 as initial investment.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, for this kind help. Accordingly, I will file the return. I was awaiting for your reply. I got your reply and I am happy and very thank full to you.

Comment: Sir, sorry to disturb you. But if u don't mind kindly let me know in part D of CG IN ITR-2 , i.e information about accrual receipt of Capital gain, there are four columns as 15/6 e.tc. Here how to distribute the capital gains? What I understood that it should be distributed on quarterly basis. That is CG earned in first quarter should be entered in frost column and gains entered in second quarter should be entered in second column like this third and fourth columns. Is this correct or is there any other way to fill these columns.

Comment: @Ravi Yes it is right. Enter the amount as per the quarter in which the gain was realized. This should match the total gain entered.